# The SAML assertion with ID [the id] is being replayed

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, deployment, saml

I'm using ComponentSpace to set up SAML for my .net core application. The IDP used is OneLogin and the Service Provider is build on top of their examples.

Everything works great on local. We deployed today and on every attempt to connect we receive the error

```
"The SAML assertion with ID [the id] is being replayed".
```

To mention that the server where we deployed the application is in Australia.

I don't understand why is being replayed if we just tried to connect. On every error we see a different id.

I tried to set the AssertionLifetime to be 24 hours

```
"AssertionLifeTime": "24:04:04"
```

But it made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

We keep a cache of previous SAML assertion IDs so we can detect possible replay attacks. Every SAML assertion has a unique ID so you should never see the same ID again. Each time we receive an assertion we check it against this cache. We throw this exception if the ID is in the cache. Under normal circumstances you should not see this type of error.

Neither the location of the server nor the assertion lifetime should have any impact. There are separate checks to ensure the assertion hasn't expired but all times are in UTC and as long as the server clocks are reasonably in sync there won't be any issues. If there were you'd see a different exception message.

It's strange you're seeing his error and even stranger that it only started after deployment. SAML responses are sent by the IdP in an HTTP Post. Is it possible there's some sort of network infrastructure or configuration that's causing these messages to be duplicated? Tracing the network traffic received by your application would help determine the cause.

Comment: I enabled serilog and sent the logs file to you guys. I hope from there we can solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks. We've replied to your email.

Answer (score 0):

I am using another IDP and SP but at least in my case, the problem was that the user logs in if the login process takes too much time the user clicks on **Back** or **Refresh** button and tries to use the same SAML assertion again.

Just as information:
Every SAML assertion has a unique ID.
The lifetime of the SAML assertion can be configured in the system.
You could check the time difference between your IDP and SP. Typically 3 seconds.